# Embed PDF on webpage and scroll horizontally to center it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I have added a PDF to a webpage using the embed tag. The width of the embed window is smaller than the width of the PDF. So, A horizontal scroll bar appears. However, there are wide margins on the left and the right of the PDF document itself. If user scrolls center to the PDF, the PDF's content fits perfectly.

I would like to have this scrolling happen automatically if possible.

The code is here http://shop.stelladoradus.com/product/gsm-repeater/
You must click on the specification tab to see the PDF.

For google chrome I did the following:

I used an Iframe instead of the embed

```
<iframe id='pdf_embed' height='1300' style='width: 734px; margin-left: -40px;' src='iframe_url?pdf=pdf_url.'></iframe>
```

on the iframe page I have:

```
<style>
object{
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -370px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
embed{
    width:100%;
    height:95%;
}
</style>
<html>
<body >
    <object height='1430' data="<?php echo $_GET['pdf']; ?>" type="application/pdf">
        <embed height='1430' src="<?php echo $_GET['pdf']; ?>" type="application/pdf" />
    </object> 
</body>
</html>
```

This solution is actually exactly what I was looking for, as the pdf is zoomed in so the margins aren't showing, and its easier to read (bigger text). I couldn't get it to work for firefox or IE, for that you can use @Infer-On solution below.

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Drop some code that you have done.

Comment: have you already tried to wrap it between a div <div style="text-align:center"> ?

Comment: @Infer-On This will center the Embed tag though, not scroll the pdf. I've added a link to clarify.

Comment: "If user scrolls center to the PDF" this is bad English, I did not write this, why was my post edited like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think you have only to pass some paramenters to your PDF, as specified from [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf):

You could try something like this:

```
zoom=scale
```

> Sets the zoom and scroll factors, using float or integer values. For 
>   example, a scale value of 100 indicates a zoom value of 100%.

or else

```
view=Fit
```

> Set the view of the displayed page, using the keyword values  defined
>   in the PDF language specification. For more information,  see the PDF
>   Reference.

See the related documentation to find the parameter will better fit for you

```
http://example.org/doc.pdf#zoom=50
http://example.org/doc.pdf#view=Fit,100
```

**EDIT**

What i already tried:

```
<object data="http://www.stelladoradus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/en_spec_RP1000G3.pdf" 
 type="application/pdf" 
 width="300" height="500">
    <param name="view" value="fit" />

</object>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/wVaGa/23/

this works, but not in Chrome...

Comment: I added a solution for Chrome in my question. Thanks for the help you got me on the right track.